# Python argparse required=True but --version functionality?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

In all my scripts I use the standard flags `--help` and `--version`, however I cannot seem to figure out how to make a `--version` with `parser.add_argument(..., required=True)`.

```
import sys, os, argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='How to get --version to work?')

parser.add_argument('--version', action='store_true', 
                    help='print version information')
parser.add_argument('-H', '--hostname', dest='hostname', required=True, 
                    help='Host name, IP Address')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--database', dest='database', required=True,
                    help='Check database with indicated name')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--username', dest='username', required=True, 
                    help='connect using the indicated username')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--password', dest='password', required=True, 
                    help='use the password to authenticate the connection')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.version == True:
    print 'Version information here'

$ ./arg.py  --version 
usage: arg.py [-h] [--version] -H HOSTNAME -d DATABASE -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD 
arg.py: error: argument -H/--hostname is required
```

Yes, I want `--hostname` *and others* required, but I *always* want `--version` to work appropriately like `--help` (and `-h`).

```
$ ./arg.py  --help   
usage: arg.py [-h] [--version] -H HOSTNAME -d DATABASE -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD

How to get --version to work?

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --version             print version information
  -H HOSTNAME, --hostname HOSTNAME
                        Host name, IP Address
  -d DATABASE, --database DATABASE
                        Check database with indicated name
  -u USERNAME, --username USERNAME
                        connect using the indicated username
  -p PASSWORD, --password PASSWORD
                        use the password to authenticate the connection
```

Any help on getting `--version` to work?

Comment: Should be (to avoid key errors:)
    if 'version' in args:
        print 'Version information here'

Answer (score 40):

There is a special *version* `action` keyword argument to `add_argument` (As documented here: [argparse#action](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action)).
Try this (copied from working code):

```
parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', 
                    action='version',                    
                    version='%(prog)s (version 0.1)')
```

Comment: As documented in http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#action, +1. Note that this is exactly what the OP asks for; a method to make a `--version` argument work, when there are `required=True` arguments.